# writing a method containsInstanceOf(Class<? extends SuperClassName>)

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I have written a class Couple

I want to write a method containsInstanceOf like this in (1),
but I get the error "can't resolve cls to a type" I've solved it by using (2).

but I don't like it at all. do you have any suggestions on writing this method more elegant and failsafe ?

(1)

```
    private boolean containsInstanceof(Class<?extends GameObject> cls) {
    return this.getFirst() instanceof cls || this.getSecond() instanceof cls;
}
```

(2)

```
    private boolean containsInstanceof(Class<?extends GameObject> cls) {
    return this.getFirst().getClass().getName().equals(cls.getName()) ||
           this.getSecond().getClass().getName().equals(cls.getName());
}
```

expected no errors in (1) but get that cls can't be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [`Class.isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method:

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator.

```
return cls.isInstance(this.getFirst()) || cls.isInstance(this.getSecond());
```